# Unable to Select System Image for Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

While setting up my emulator I am unable to select any system image to proceed further.

[image: Error Prompt]

Comment: Yeah because you need to download first.

Comment: please look at the picture I have attached kindly, and tel me the exact steps.

Comment: Dude I told you the solution that you have not downloaded any image so you need to download it first.

Comment: You can download it from android sdk manager.

Answer (score 1):

Open your SDK Manager from your IDE and download the system image from there